# ENOENT, stat '-stylus' at Error (native)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, npm, stylus

I've this strange error message while using stylus, first i install nodejs for github on my linux machine, then i ran this command `npm install -g stylus autoprefixer-stylus` and i got this error log/message

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus']
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES, unlink \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-24-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "stylus" "autoprefixer-stylus"
npm ERR! cwd /home/avinashizhere
npm ERR! node -v v0.13.0-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus'
npm ERR! stack     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus']
npm ERR! error rolling back   stack: 'Error: EACCES, unlink \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus' }
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

what is understood is, i've to use `sudo` to run this, i did add `sudo` and i got this output

```
/usr/local/bin/stylus -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus
autoprefixer-stylus@0.4.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/autoprefixer-stylus
└── autoprefixer-core@4.0.2 (caniuse-db@1.0.30000037, postcss@3.0.7)

stylus@0.49.3 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus
├── css-parse@1.7.0
├── mkdirp@0.3.5
├── sax@0.5.8
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── source-map@0.1.41 (amdefine@0.1.0)
└── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
```

now i think i've need package/files with me, now i ran this command `stylus -u autoperfixer -stylus -w style.styl` and i'm getting this

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:625
    if (err) throw err;
                   ^
Error: ENOENT, stat '-stylus'
    at Error (native)
```

I don't know what is wrong, or is there something i'm missing?

Comment: It’s `autoprefixer-stylus`, not `autoperfixer -stylus`.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a wrong command, to install stylus run on the terminal:

```
 sudo npm install -g stylus
```

Then if you want to install autoprefixer-stylus run:

```
 sudo npm install -g autoprefixer-stylus
```

Answer (score 0):

> now i think i've need package/files with me, now i ran this command `stylus -u autoperfixer -stylus` -w style.styl and i'm getting this

It’s `autoprefixer-stylus`, not `autoperfixer -stylus`.

Comment: stylus -u autoprefixer-stylus -w style.styl
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:625
    if (err) throw err;
                   ^
Error: ENOENT, stat 'style.styl'
    at Error (native)

Comment: @avinashizhere: `style.styl` doesn’t exist. What is your Stylus stylesheet called, and where is it?